# What is the perl equivalent for telnet foo.com 80?

Tags: perl

If someone can't:

```
echo | telnet foo.com 657
```

then how could it do the same with perl? Just to test, if a port is open or not.

UPDATE:

```
perl -e 'system("echo | telnet foo.com 657")'
```

is not good, because it still gives the "[No environment-specified terminal type.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102792/telnet-no-environment-specified-terminal-type)". +updated port

Comment: `system("echo | telnet foo.com 80")`?

Answer (score 3):

To actually speak TELNET protocol, you can use [Net::Telnet](http://search.cpan.org/~jrogers/Net-Telnet-3.04/lib/Net/Telnet.pm). But this isn't really what you want.

However, to just check that a remote host is alive, you can use [Net::Ping](http://search.cpan.org/~smpeters/Net-Ping-2.41/lib/Net/Ping.pm) which offers testing via various protocols, including TCP on port 80.

Answer (score 2):

Most people using telnet that way don't actually want to use the telnet protocol. It's just a convenient way to send data over a [socket](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO%3a%3aSocket%3a%3aINET).

Given that you mentoined port 80, you might actually want to place an HTTP request. You could use [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP%3a%3aUserAgent) for that.

Answer (score 1):

To just do a basic socket connection, use socket.

[perldoc socket](http://perldoc.perl.org/Socket.html#SYNOPSIS)

Their first example:

```
 use Socket qw(PF_INET SOCK_STREAM pack_sockaddr_in inet_aton);
 socket(my $socket, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)
     or die "socket: $!";
 connect($socket, pack_sockaddr_in(80, inet_aton("localhost")))
     or die "connect: $!";
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use Net::Telnet to set the terminal type for the remote side.

There is an example in the Net:Telnet documentation.